# No 750x1334 Launch Image option available in Xamarin for iPhone 6s?

Tags: ios, xamarin

Title pretty much explains itself. Under my info.plist I have the options to add a 320x480, 640x960, and 640x1136 launch images, but I am developing currently for iPhone 6s....is the 640x1136 really the one I want or is there some kind of bug with no 750x1334 option showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set all of the launch images in the info.plist, however you should really use the new storyboard or xib launch screen option: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/

To set just images you will need to use an asset catalog: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/#Managing_Launch_Screens_with_Asset_Catalogs

or you can specify in the info.plist manually: http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2014/09/iphone-6-and-6-plus-launch-images-for.html

Comment: Okay I'll take a look at those options.  Do you by chance know if this is a Xamarin bug?  I always found it really convenient to just add the image through the info.plist screen, but if going through the storyboard/xib is the new way of doing it then so be it I guess.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more details on it :) As you could manually specify or use the asset catalog.